# Android fastscroll: how to reduce the working area of the thumb

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll

In my application, I have a ListView and I activate the "fastscroll" flag.

It is works fine but it starts even if I put my thumb at 1 centimeter of the right edge of my screen, while I notice that in other applications it is necessary to put it at the end of the screen.
Is it customizable please?

Thanks